# Текст вылазит за пределы блока по высоте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть три блока. Из-за разной высоты контента блоки имеют разную длину. С помощью JS я вычисляю высоту наибольшего из блоков и присваиваю ее всем блокам. Но возникает проблема: при увеличении масштаба текст заголовка  заползает на мой абзац 



. Как это исправить, я не знаю. Прошу помощи. В блоке заголовка поигрался со свойствами **overflow** и **overflow-x**, не помогло (вернее помогло, но мне надо без скролла). Вот мой код: (На JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxjc165v/)

Контейнер с блоками на странице:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <article id="first">
                <h2>
                    ЗАГОЛОВОК 1-ПЕРВОГО БЛОКА
                    <span>БОЛЕЕ ТОЧНОЕ ОПИСАНИЯ ДЛЯ ЗАГОЛОВКА ПЕРВОГО БЛОКА</span>
                </h2>

                <p>
                    ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
                    <a href="#">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                </p>
            </article>

            <article id="second">
                <h2>
                    ЗАГОЛОВОК 2-ВОТОРОГО БЛОКА 
                    <span>БОЛЕЕ ТОЧНОЕ ОПИСАНИЯ ДЛЯ ВОТОРОГО ПЕРВОГО БЛОКА</span>
                </h2>

                <p>
                    ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
                    <a href="#">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                </p>
            </article>

            <article id="third">
                <h2>
                    ЗАГОЛОВОК 3-ТРЕТЬЕГО БЛОКА
                    <span>БОЛЕЕ ТОЧНОЕ ОПИСАНИЯ ДЛЯ ТРЕТЬЕГО ПЕРВОГО БЛОКА</span>
                </h2>

                <p>
                    ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ ТЕКСТ
                    <a href="#">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                </p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS стили:

```
    h1 {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

article {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

article:last-child {
    margin: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

article h2 {
    padding: 0 0 2% 0; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #000000;
}

article h2 span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

article p {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em 2.5em 2em 2.5em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

article p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

article p a:hover {
    color: #db9a28;
}
```

Мой скрипт:

```
function setHeight() {

    var headerHeight1 = $('#first h2').height();
    var headerHeight2 = $('#second h2').height();
    var headerHeight3 = $('#third h2').height();

    var maxHeaderHeight = headerHeight1;

    if (maxHeaderHeight <= headerHeight2) 
    {
        maxHeaderHeight = headerHeight2;

        if (maxHeaderHeight <= headerHeight3)
            maxHeaderHeight = headerHeight3; 
    }

    $('#first h2').css({
        height: maxHeaderHeight + 'px'
    });

    $('#second h2').css({
        height: maxHeaderHeight + 'px'
    });

    $('#third h2').css({
        height: maxHeaderHeight + 'px'
    });

    // for <p> tag

    var pHeight1 = $('#first p').height();
    var pHeight2 = $('#second p').height();
    var pHeight3 = $('#third p').height();

    var maxPHeight = pHeight1;

    if (maxPHeight <= pHeight2) 
    {
        maxPHeight = pHeight2;

        if (maxPHeight <= pHeight3)
            maxPHeight = pHeight3; 
    }

    $('#first p').css({
        height: maxPHeight + 'px'
    });

    $('#second p').css({
        height: maxPHeight + 'px'
    });

    $('#third p').css({
        height: maxPHeight + 'px'
    });
}

setHeight(); 
$(window).resize(setHeight);
```

Comment: Непонятно, что не так и что требуется.

Comment: Вот тут более свежая версия: https://jsfiddle.net/rxjc165v/10/ Проблема в том, что при увеличении масштаба текст заголовка вылазит за пределы блока, хотя по идее высота у блока всегда подстраивается под высоту контента. Я не знаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты задаёшь блокам фиксированную высоту. При изменении масштаба ширина окна меняется, текст перераспределяется по строкам, а зафиксированная высота не меняется. Поэтому текст не помещается в блок.

Если требуется сделать именно скритпом, то надо подписываться на изменение размера окна, убирать заданные высоты и заново выбирать максимум.

Но вообще, было бы лучше реализовать всё при помощи css.

---

> мой js-код и так срабатывает каждый раз при изменении окна. Я же использую $(window).resize()

Да, но дальше ты берёшь высоту элементов, а там при предыдущем запуске функции прописаны фиксированные значения - ты их считываешь (они все равны) и присваиваешь ещё раз.

Повторяю, перед читыванием надо сбросить эти значения, установив `auto`.

Кстати, эффективнее будет сначала 3 раза установить, потом 3 раза прочитать, потом снова 3 раза установить. И да, нехорошо каждый раз искать одни и те же dom-элементы.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой js-код и так срабатывает каждый раз при изменении окна. Я же использую $(window).resize()

Comment: @Geronimo, я дополнил ответ, но вообще, нужная фраз там уже была.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! Я как-то и не подумал сбрасывать значения высот.